# Assistance with an expression in SSRS 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have one column in a table that shows the total number of transactions. This can be toggled to show how long the transaction took to complete - eg 10 for 10 minutes, etc.

I have added another column where I would like to give the total of transactions where the time to do the transaction is listed as `0 (zero).`

I have tried things `like =count(fields!transactiontime.value < 1)` but this just returns the total of all transactions, not those `<0`.

Any suggestions for this elementary yet infuriating problem would be appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try;

`=Sum(Iif(Fields!transactiontime.Value = 0, 1, 0))`

Basically with this expression the `Iif` will evaluate each transactiontime and, if it's 0, return a 1. The `Sum` then simply aggregates the results of all the `Iif`s, adding them up to give you the answer.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Very many thanks for taking the time to answer my query.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I have totally missed your point but is it not just a case of `=COUNT(Fields!transactiontime.Value = 0)`

EDIT:

I that case I think that you need to do the following:

In the cell where you would like to count the total number of transactions but in the following expression:

```
=CountDistinct(IIF(Fields!transactiontime.Value=0, Fields!{YOUR UNIQUE TRANSACTION FIELD NAME HERE}.Value, nothing))
```

Let me know how you get on. If this does not resolve the issue you may need to upload your rdl somewhere for us to have a look at.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. What you suggested was what I tried first, then I tried =COUNT(Fields!transactiontime.value <1). Unfortunately the value returned = the total number of transactions, not those that = 0. It's most perplexing.

Comment: I think you are mistaken Dan, the IIF statement will return either the unique transaction field name which Will has not said what it is, that's why I put the description for this in curly braces, or nothing and then the CountDisinct will count the number of different transactions based on this ID/unique transaction field name's value.

Comment: You are totally right devBarn, I'm sorry I misread your expression there.